# cannot change voice in pyttsx3 using setProperty

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

I want **tamil** voice in python text to speech but I cannot change voice from default to any other languages. I tried this code

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
   if voice.id == 'tamil':
       engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
       print(engine.getProperty('voice'))
       break
```

but the print statement still prints default.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve your question, and I concluded that when you run the line:

```
engine.runAndWait()
```

That's when the parameters are set in your variable engine.
So, you can try with the next code:

```
import pyttsx3;
engine = pyttsx3.init();
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
idVoice = 0
for voice in voices:
   idVoice = idVoice + 1
   if voice.id == 'tamil':
       print("void ID: ", voice.id)
       engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
       engine.say("My new message...")
       engine.runAndWait()
       print(engine.getProperty('voice'))
       break
print(idVoice)
engine.setProperty('rate',170)
engine.setProperty('volume', 0.9)
print("The new voice: ", engine.getProperty('voice'))
```

Answer (score 0):

pyttsx3 not read tamil but read thanlish. why you can try  tamil to convert into thanlish.

```
import pyttsx3 as py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("thanlish.cvs")
B = pd.DataFrame(data)
c = "வல்லினம்"
print(c)
for i,j in zip(B["key"],B["value"]):
    if i in c:
        c=c.replace(i,j)
print(c)
py.speak(c)
```

output:
வல்லினம்
vallinam